# Is it possible to fetch mails from desktop outlook application through java?

Tags: java, outlook

I got a requirement to read all the unread mails from outlook desktop application and store them onto a excel sheet. is it possible to fetch mails from outlook application through java program?

Comment: From outlook? Or from the mail server?

Comment: its from outlook application installed on desktop not from the server

Comment: Hi, I am looking for similar solution. Seems there are some jars available which allows to access COM interface. Did you find solution ?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution to fetch from desktop application